# CakePHP paginate action

Tags: pagination, cakephp-2.0

Can you also tell why sorting don't work with this action:

```
    public function admin_view($id = null)
{
   if (!$this->Category->exists($id)) {
      throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid product'));
   }
   $this->Paginator->settings = array(
          'conditions' => array(
                       'Category.' . $this->Category->primaryKey => $id), 
       'limit' => $this->limit
   );
   $this->set('category', $this->paginate('Category'));
}
```

and view looks this:

```
<th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('price'); ?></th>
<?php foreach ($category[0]['Product'] as $product): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo h($product['price']); ?>&nbsp;</td>         
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

When I click on price it refresh my page, but sorting not working. Something wrong, I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function view($id = null)
{
   if (!$this->Product->exists($id)) {
      throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid product'));
   }

   $this->Paginator->settings = array(
          'conditions' => array(
                       'Product.' . $this->Product->primaryKey => $id)
   );
   $this->set('product', $this->paginate('Product');
}
```

Comment: Can u please specify the link produced by sort function.

Comment: http://cakephp/admin/categories/view/59/sort:price/direction:desc This link i got after click price, but nothing cnhanges.

Comment: did you notice that your function name is admin_view and the link call the function named 'view'

Comment: I have function view and I have also function admin_view and I have view admin_view and view, admin is just prefix. So my function admin_view call view admin_view. I think problem in somethink else.
http://cakephp/categories/view/59/sort:price/direction:asc this link call view